# Visual Studio - Publishing To Git Hub - User Cancelled Certification Check

Tags: git, github

I am trying to publish for the first time my visual studio Kentico project to github.

When I try to publish the project, I get the following error:

"User cancelled certificate check:"

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What commands did you ran exactly?

Comment: I am using github for visual studio no commands

Comment: It tells you that you must configure your remote... are you using windows? Do you know git bash?

Comment: Can you see : https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/1532